# alternatives to a JavaScript telnet system

Tags: javascript, language-agnostic

I have a javascript telnet interface, which allows users to telnet to machines booked in to my site. It is a true vt102 emulation, and requires only a browser and JavaScript on the clients machine.

However, it is really a hybrid, and the telnet system really runs on the server with only screen updates and keystrokes passing between the browser and the server.

I was wondering rather than developing a JavaScript telnet system if its possible to come up with some newer ways.

What are some possibilities?

Comment: Interesting question. Can you re-phrase it as something more answerable?

Comment: There is a mind boggling number of possibilities.  What are you requirements?  This might be better answered on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ btw, since it's more of a generic architecture question from what I can tell.

Comment: bzlm I think the question is answerable possibilities within the current system and or a more dynamic approach using any other method I dont think Pete is correct in the mind boggling number of possibilities tho, but would be nice to see some approaches that I could consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think there is a way to implement a telnet client within a browser using only Javascript.

I've seen Java applets that can create telnet sessions. I do not think there is any way to have plain Javascript create a telnet session. You could install a browser plugin, but at that point you might as well install a telnet client. If you restrict your users to Internet Explorer and you can get them to save a file onto their machine, you could use an HTML Application (.hta file) but at that point you are also effectively installing software on to the local machine.